# Keycloak allow user to create new users

Tags: permissions, keycloak

I have a `admin` role on my realm and a `user-admin` role for my `test` client.

The `user-admin` is only allowed to view users, edit them and map roles from the `test` client. I also want the `user-admin` to create new users.

Sadly the "Add User" Button is not displayed when i log in using a user-admin.
The only way to allow the `user-admin` to create users is to add the `manage-users` role from the `ream-management` client as a composite.

The problem with the `manage-users` role is that it also allows to view and edit groups and to map every role there is including my `admin` realm role.

I tried using the `map-role` permission from the `admin` role itself. That did not work and it seems that the `manage-users` role simply overweights the permissions of the role.

I'd expect something like a `create` permission for the Users ressouce but can't find anything like that.

Thanks,

Maik

Comment: I woudl like to have a create-users permission too. manage-users role allows too much permissions.